# Add custom fonts in customizer

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm using Olympus theme (with Unyson). I want to add some custom fonts to fonts list in customizer. I tried all ways but my custom fonts doesn't appear in the list. I defined fonts eot, woff and eot files in main style file of theme.

Only adding the font name in the dropdown list is the target. Fonts are Vazir and Yekan.

```
@font-face {
font-family: Vazir;
src: url('../fonts/Vazir.eot');
src: url('../fonts/Vazir.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../fonts/Vazir.woff') format('woff'),
url('../fonts/Vazir.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;}

@font-face {
font-family: Yekan;
src: url('../fonts/Yekan.eot');
src: url('../fonts/Yekan.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../fonts/Yekan.woff') format('woff'),
url('../fonts/Yekan.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;}
```